# Time Machine file hierarchy being added to - folders have been added

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

some 2 weeks ago I got my computer back from Apple service in which they had to wipe it.  I restored the time machine backup with no issues and have been using it since - waiting to make sure all is running smooth before doing another back up.  I did the back up today and when I took a peak at my external backup directory I noticed folders in the back up directory which have been named w/ appended names and which I do not have on my original file structure or that show mounted in disk utility.  When I called apple and showed them and asked, what were they, the advisor said, "Great question - Shouldn't be doing that.  Ive never seen that and don't have a precedent for that."  They had me run First Aid on my external drive.  Ran with no errors reported.

Question:  Why were the folders added/renamed with the 1 and 1 1 suffixes?  Is this normal behavior and what does it mean?

Current disk structure from disk utility
[image: Disk structure]

Folders from Time Machine backup
[image: Back up directory]

here is the back up progression and then the latest back up before this service a few weeks ago.  there was. no change in directory structure from no. 3 backup and last b4 service so I skipped all those.

[image: backup1]
[image: backup2]
[image: backup3]
[image: last bu before service]
[image: file structure]

Comment: Can you please list the contents of those directories? Can you please show which partitions are backed up by Time Machine?

Comment: Can you please also list the contents of the last backup before Apple service? The Recovery partition should not be backed up in normal cases.

Comment: I don't think this is a normal case. Have you looked at your TM backup log?

Comment: Joy- as far as I know its McIntosh HD getting backed up.  I don't see in TM where to chose another source....  "List Contents of those directories" - which ones??  What TM log are you referring to?  Where do I find it?  Tks

Comment: Those directories: Macintosh HD, Macintosh HD - Data, etc.

Comment: TM log: I believe those can be collected using the command ```tmdiagnose```